# Giving a game object velocity/speed and converting vectors points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I'm currently developing a game in unity using c# scripts and I have a small problem. I'm trying to give one of my game objects a constant speed/velocity without it being affected by other gravity, drag or any other type of physics characteristic except velocity. I looked through the Unity manual to find any classes that would be able to help me with this and I seemed to have found one class that would do the job:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

I edited it in order to make it fit my game since this is a game object that doesn't have its velocity affected by the player but every time I run the game in the test screen nothing happens(The object stays static). I was wondering if anyone knows of a class in Unity or C# that deals with this problem or generally knows how I can make this happen. Both by having it affect all the game objects appearing on the screen at the same time or only a select few? And secondly, I was also wondering how I could convert the rigidbody velocity vector2 into from a world point into a screen point?

Thanks alot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallSpeed : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 100);

    }
}

Expected result: The game object moves upwards with a speed of 100.
Actual result: Nothing happens.
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the object in question and anything that may appear in your console? (Basically, just your scene running.)

Comment: You're using a `Vector2` so you should probably be using a `Rigidbody2D`, not a `Rigidbody`.

Comment: check the checkbox "Is Kinematic" on Rigidbody, to move by velocity off it

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make your object move at a constant speed, there is no need for a rigidbody reference.

```
public float upSpeedPerSecond = 100f;

void Update() {
    transform.translate(new Vector3(0, upSpeedPerSecond*time.deltaTime, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check that your `Rigidbody2D` is set to dynamic in the inspector, as Kinematic and Static rigidbodies do not have physics. If you don't want it to be dynamic, just use `rb.Translate()` instead. However, **NEVER** translate a static rigidbody, as it messes with the optimizations the engine does to them, use kinematic rigidbodies for transforming instead.